# NULL not generated in last line of a GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP query

Tags: mysql, null, group-by, subtotal

I have a table containing a Date filed and a number.
I want to display ordered Month names as grouping fields using a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(Day,'%M'), 'TOTAL') As Month,
  SUM(Money) As USD
FROM mytable
WHERE
  Day
    BETWEEN
      concat(date_format(now(),'%Y-'),'01-01')
    AND
      concat(date_format(now(),'%Y-'),'12-31')
GROUP BY
  DATE_FORMAT(Day,'%m') 
  WITH ROLLUP;
```

I Obtain:

```
+----------+--------+
| Month    | USD    |
+----------+--------+
| January  |  103.5 |
| February | 119.25 |
| March    | 163.25 |
| April    |    102 |
| May      | 124.75 |
| June     |   72.5 |
| June     | 685.25 |
+----------+--------+
```

Why the grand total line has no NULL value that is substitued ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your GROUP BY expression should be the same as the one in the SELECT, so thet you would have `NULL` against your TOTAL. You will have to rewrite the query. And I would suggest to avoid names that coincide with MySQL keywords and function names (at least quote them).

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(ELT(m,
               'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
               'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
               'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'),
           'TOTAL') as `Month`,
  USD
FROM (
  SELECT 
    MONTH(`Day`) As m,
    SUM(Money) As USD
  FROM mytable
  WHERE
    `Day`
      BETWEEN
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1)
      AND
        LAST_DAY(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 365))
  GROUP BY
    MONTH(`Day`) 
    WITH ROLLUP) as sums
```

Comment: Wonderful !
Elegant, clear solution with an excellent explanation.

Comment: Yet I still wonder WHY? I encountered a very similar issue (thus me being here) and solved it but it feels less efficient as I had to use a TEXT field rather than a PK...